# Can this driver be simplified?

Tags: led, driver

I have this driver. It has two MOSFETs and two complementary signals to drive them:

[image: Driver]

The load (a bunch of LEDs) sees 5 V or 0 V and, in average, they take a maximum of 100 mA.
However, the top MOSFET needs a driver signal that is not referenced to ground, which makes things a bit complicated.

I am looking for a similar driver that:

- is simple (it does not have many components).
- does not need floating signals (and ideally only one control signal).
- does not have any big resistors in the 100 mA path to avoid losses (in voltage or in power)
- is an all or nothing driver (5 V or 0 V), so the LEDs light up properly when they are ON.

I am open to any suggestions (with BJTs, with extra components to create the floating driver signal from the pins of the microcontroller, etc.).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why does your driver require a pull-down (the lower) transistor? (Can you see why we use component designators, M1, M2, etc., on our schematics?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't mentioned in the original question: -

\$\color{red}{\text{That the LEDs couldn't be electrically disconnected from ground}}\$

Speed of operation wasn't mentioned either and neither was there any mention of the input logic circuit being inverted so, try this as a simplification: -

[image]

You will still need to ensure that the LEDs can handle 5 volts with no chance of an over-current situation.

> I am looking for a similar driver that:
>
> - is simple (it does not have many components). \$\color{red}{\text{YES}}\$
> - does not need floating signals (and ideally only one control signal). \$\color{red}{\text{YES}}\$
> - does not have any big resistors in the 100 mA path to avoid losses (in voltage or in power) \$\color{red}{\text{you need to be more forthcoming about what you currently do}}\$
> - is an all or nothing driver (5 V or 0 V), so the LEDs light up properly when they are ON. \$\color{red}{\text{YES}}\$

PMOS load switch: -

[image]

Image from [Using MOSFETs in Load Switch Applications](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/_media/pdfs/application-notes/and9093-d-mosfets-as-load-switches.pdf).

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thank you for your fast response. I'm sorry if I was not clear 100%
I should have said that I considered your option. However, the LEDs can only be driven from the +5 V (historical reasons of this circuit), and therefore I can't change the LED ground. That's is why this is the driver that is currently being used.

Comment: Then use a positive side (high side) PMOS transistor. It doesn't need to be push-pull (unless there is something else that you haven't said) and there's no need for a floating driver. You will need an N channel MOSFET to control the PMOSFET though. It's up to you.

Comment: That is exactly what I need!! I don't know why I never thought about that before! There's nothing that I didn't say. Thanks for your help Andy!